# Extract date part from datetime in SQL Server Compact 3.5

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server Compact 3.5 version for a small application. I want to extract the date part from a column (which is of `datetime` data type) and I used following query to try and do that:

```
string qry = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE(Finger_Record) as [Working Date] FROM dt_raw_data ";
```

When I execute it, I am getting a error saying `DATE` function is not a function in SQL Server Compact. Then how can I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it is work for me

```
select distinct CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Finger_Record,110) as [Working Date]  from dt_raw_data
```

Comment: it worked with small modification to the data type instead of varchar I used nvarchar.Thanks Singh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
string qry = "SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), Finger_Record, 101) as [Working Date] FROM dt_raw_data ";
```

Comment: answer is edited..follow that and for your reference i am sharing the link what you can follow:https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174450(v=sql.110).aspx